# speed up code - vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization, nested-loops

I'm not really familiar with `vectorization`, but I am aware that, amongst `MATLAB`'s strengths, code vectorization is probably the most rewarded.

I have this code:

```
ikx= (-Nx/2:Nx/2-1)*dk1;
iky= (-Ny/2:Ny/2-1)*dk2;
ikz= (-Nz/2:Nz/2-1)*dk3;

[k1,k2,k3] = ndgrid(ikx,iky,ikz);
k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);
Cij = zeros(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz);
count = 0;
for ii = 1:Nx
    for jj = 1:Ny
        for kk = 1:Nz
            if ~isequal(k1(ii,jj,kk),0)
                count = count +1;
                fprintf('iteration step %i\r\n',count)
                E_int = interp1(k_vec,E_vec,k(ii,jj,kk),'spline','extrap');
                beta = c*gamma./(k(ii,jj,kk).*sqrt(E_int));
                k30 = k3(ii,jj,kk) + beta*k1(ii,jj,kk);
                k0 = sqrt(k1(ii,jj,kk)^2 + k2(ii,jj,kk)^2 + k30^2);
                Ek0 = 1.453*(k0^4/((1 + k0^2)^(17/6)));
                B = sigmaiso*sqrt((Ek0./(k0.^2))*((dk1*dk2*dk3)/(4*pi)));
                C1 = ((beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk).^2).*(k0.^2 - 2*k30.^2 + k30.*beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk)))./(k(ii,jj,kk).^2.*(k1(ii,jj,kk).^2 + k2(ii,jj,kk).^2));
                C2 = ((k2(ii,jj,kk).*(k0.^2))./((k1(ii,jj,kk).^2 + k2(ii,jj,kk).^2).^(3/2))).*atan2((beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk).*sqrt(k1(ii,jj,kk).^2 + k2(ii,jj,kk).^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk)));
                xhsi1 = C1 - C2.*(k2(ii,jj,kk)./k1(ii,jj,kk));
                xhsi2 = C1.*(k2(ii,jj,kk)./k1(ii,jj,kk)) + C2;
                Cij(1,1,ii,jj,kk) = B.*((k2(ii,jj,kk).*xhsi1)./(k0));
                Cij(1,2,ii,jj,kk) = B.*((k3(ii,jj,kk)-k1(ii,jj,kk).*xhsi1+beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk))./(k0));
                Cij(1,3,ii,jj,kk) = B.*(-k2(ii,jj,kk)./(k0));
                Cij(2,1,ii,jj,kk) = B.*((k2(ii,jj,kk).*xhsi2-k3(ii,jj,kk)-beta.*k1(ii,jj,kk))./(k0));
                Cij(2,2,ii,jj,kk) = B.*((-k1(ii,jj,kk).*xhsi2)./(k0));
                Cij(2,3,ii,jj,kk) = B.*(k1(ii,jj,kk)./(k0));
                Cij(3,1,ii,jj,kk) = B.*(k2(ii,jj,kk).*k0./(k(ii,jj,kk).^2));
                Cij(3,2,ii,jj,kk) = B.*(-k1(ii,jj,kk).*k0./(k(ii,jj,kk).^2));               
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Generally, I might avoid the nested `for` loops; nonetheless, the `if` statement on `k1` values is currently directing me towards the classical and old-fashion code structure.

I blatantly would like to bypass the presence of the `for` loops in favour of vectorized and more elegant solution.

Any support is more than welcome.

**EDIT**

To let better understand what the code is expected to perform, I hereby provide you with some basics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT2**

As @Floris advised, I came up with this alternative solution:

```
ikx= (-Nx/2:Nx/2-1)*dk1;
iky= (-Ny/2:Ny/2-1)*dk2;
ikz= (-Nz/2:Nz/2-1)*dk3;

[k1,k2,k3] = ndgrid(ikx,iky,ikz);
k = sqrt(k1.^2 + k2.^2 + k3.^2);

ii = (ikx ~= 0);
k1w = k1(ii,:,:);
k2w = k2(ii,:,:);
k3w = k3(ii,:,:);
kw = k(ii,:,:);

E_int = interp1(k_vec,E_vec,kw,'spline','extrap');
beta = c*gamma./(kw.*sqrt(E_int));

k30 = k3w + beta.*k1w;
k0 = sqrt(k1w.^2 + k2w.^2 + k30.^2);
Ek0 = (1.453*k0.^4)./((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6));
B = sqrt((2*(pi^2)*(l^3))*(Ek0./(V*k0.^4)));

k1w_2 = k1w.^2;
k2w_2 = k2w.^2;
k30_2 = k30.^2;
k0_2 = k0.^2;
kw_2 = kw.^2;

C1 = ((beta.*k1w_2).*(k0_2 - 2.*k30_2 + beta.*k1w.*k30))./(kw_2.*(k1w_2 + k2w_2));
C2 = ((k2w.*k0_2)./((k1w_2 + k2w_2).^(3/2))).*atan2((beta.*k1w).*sqrt(k1w_2 + k2w_2),(k0_2 - k30.*k1w.*beta));

xhsi1 = C1 - (k2w./k1w).*C2;
xhsi2 = (k2w./k1w).*C1 + C2;

Cij = zeros(3,3,Nx,Ny,Nz);

Cij(1,1,ii,:,:) = B.*(k2w.*xhsi1);
Cij(1,2,ii,:,:) = B.*(k3w - k1w.*xhsi1 + beta.*k1w);
Cij(1,3,ii,:,:) = B.*(-k2w);
Cij(2,1,ii,:,:) = B.*(k2w.*xhsi2 - k3w - beta.*k1w);
Cij(2,2,ii,:,:) = B.*(-k1w.*xhsi2);
Cij(2,3,ii,:,:) = B.*(k1w);
Cij(3,1,ii,:,:) = B.*((k0_2./kw_2).*k2w);
Cij(3,2,ii,:,:) = B.*(-(k0_2./kw_2).*k1w);
```

Comment: start simple: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a 5 dimensional array (`Cij`)? Speed is usually a function of how close things are in memory and you are spreading them out far. Maybe 8 arrays of 3 dims would serve you better.

Comment: Remove the `fprintf()` from the inner loop. If you want speed, do not so any I/O in the main loop.

Comment: maybe you could explain what the code does in general (variables and operations) ? to be honest its very hard to follow the code with all ii,kk stuff :)

Comment: I will remove `fprintf` later on: it's not fundamental within the code.

Comment: @thang: the vectorized code is the same as with `for` loops. but how do I account for `k1~=0` statement?

Comment: Within your nested loops, I don't see anything that depends on something other than the current indices (`ii,jj,kk`) so this should be straightforward to vectorize.  The only 'gotcha' might be if your `interp1` step depends on previous iterations, but I don't think it does (you don't include the definitions of all the parameters though).  Within the inner loop, make your single-value calculations do a 3D matrix instead.  Then get rid of the indices for the rest of it, and do the entire matrix at once.  You can check for your condition all at once either before or after the calculations.

Comment: @tmpearce: if you mean `k_vec` and `E_vec`, those are tabled arrays generated in another script. Calling them from a table let me save computation time.

Comment: @fpe That's fine... have you tried vectorizing like I suggested?  The `if` statement really shouldn't be a problem since you can generate an `N-D logical matrix` that tells you when your calculation is invalid, you don't have to do it element-wise.

Comment: About the k1~=0 - if you remove it from ikx you won't have it. Could use `setdiff`.

Comment: how often is it that it's 0?  if it's not so often, you can go ahead and compute it and then mask out afterwards.  if it's very often, then vectorizing may not help much.  however, it may also help if you restructure your equation so that the ~0 is seamlessly built in.  matlab sometimes is smart about determining that a matrix is sparse and optimizing for it.

Comment: assuming that `k1(4096,32,32)`, `k1(2049,:,:) == 0`, therefore `32*32` zeros within `k1`

Comment: @tmpearce - I believe that the code I provided as an answer follows your suggestion quite closely, although I hadn't read your comment when I wrote it. So consider this a tip of the hat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your test just once, and then create arrays of "just the elements you need". Example:

```
% create an index of all the elements that are worth computing:
worthComputing = find(k1(:)~=0);
% now create sub-arrays of all the other arrays... a little bit expensive on memory,
% but much faster for computation:
kw =  k(worthComputing);
k1w = k1(worthComputing);
k2w = k2(worthComputing);
k3w = k3(worthComputing);

% now we'll compute all the results of the innermost for loop in single statements:
E_int = interp1(k_vec,E_vec,kw,'spline','extrap');
beta = c*gamma./kw.*sqrt(E_int));
k30 = k3w + beta*k1w;
k0 = sqrt(k1w.^2 + k2w.^2 + k30.^2);
Ek0 = 1.453*(k0.^4/((1 + k0.^2).^(17/6)));
```

% the next line has `dk1`, `dk2`, `dk3` ... not sure what they are? Not shown to be initialized. Assuming scalars as they are not indexed.

```
B = sigmaiso*sqrt((Ek0./(k0.^2))*((dk1*dk2*dk3)/(4*pi)));
C1 = ((beta.*k1w.^2).*(k0.^2 - 2*k30.^2 + k30.*beta.*k1w))./(kw.^2.*(k1w.^2 + k2w.^2));
C2 = ((k2w.*(k0.^2))./((k1w.^2 + k2w.^2).^(3/2))).*atan2((beta.*k1w.*sqrt(k1w.^2 + ...
    k2w.^2)),(k0.^2 - k30.*beta.*k1w));
xhsi1 = C1 - C2.*(k2w./k1w);
xhsi2 = C1.*(k2w./k1w) + C2;
```

% in the next lines I am using the trick of "collapsing" the remaining indices
% in other words, Matlab figures out that I want to access the elements in C
% that correspond to the `ii, jj, kk` that were picked before...

```
Cij(1,1,worthComputing) = B.*((k2w.*xhsi1)./(k0));
Cij(1,2,worthComputing) = B.*((k3w-k1w.*xhsi1+beta.*k1w)./(k0));
Cij(1,3,worthComputing) = B.*(-k2w./(k0));
Cij(2,1,worthComputing) = B.*((k2w.*xhsi2-k3w-beta.*k1w)./(k0));
Cij(2,2,worthComputing) = B.*((-k1w.*xhsi2)./(k0));
Cij(2,3,worthComputing) = B.*(k1w./(k0));
Cij(3,1,worthComputing) = B.*(k2w.*k0./(kw.^2));
Cij(3,2,worthComputing) = B.*(-k1w.*k0./(kw.^2));
```

It is entirely possible there's a typo or two in the above - but this is the basic approach to vectorization.